# Microsoft azure notebooks import Pandas-Datareader issue

Tags: pandas, azure, jupyter-notebook, pandas-datareader

I am quite new to Microsoft Azure Notebooks, I am having quite issue installing packages to run my notebooks and in particularly in installing Pandas-datareader

I used a simple requirements.txt `file https://notebooks.azure.com/r-bendenoun/projects/investments-notebooks/html/requirements.txt`

that I linked to my notebook however when I run it I get ImportError: No module named pandas_datareader

I have the feeling that not every packages in my requirements.txt file are properly installed.

I tried using terminal but I get requirement already satisfied

any idea ??

Comment: Try changing `pandas_datareader` to `pandas-datareader` in your `requirements.txt` (hyphen, instead of underscore) ...? and also maybe try `pip install pandas-datareader -U`  (upgrade flag)

Comment: nop the hyphen does not work and the documentation says that using import pandas_datareader as pdr is the proper way

Comment: yes underscore for import... but hyphen for installing with the requirements .txt via pip